# XCode6 keeps crashing when I try to export ad-hoc build

Tags: crash, xcode6, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

[UPDATE]
Problem has been solved after going Apple dev site and accept new Term and Condition agreement, this is the most strange problem I ever seen.

I am able to build and run app without any problem until create ad-hoc build, Xcode6 (version 6.0.1) will always crash after choosing account and team and throw below exception:

```
Process:         Xcode [1861]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 712682811
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [258]
Responsible:     Xcode [1861]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-26 13:07:23.360 +0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  E2DD7234-2A56-B169-B657-56CFED90D316


Crashed Thread:  10  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A317
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
```

Is anyone experiencing this? please help.
Note: I already choose team in Target config.

Comment: I had the same problem. Already started to download Xcode 5.1.1 to downgrade. But accepting new Terms on the apple dev site solves the problem. You save my day!